# Error Empty Link - Accessbility - How to fix this?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm trying to make a website accessible and it says "ERROR - EMPTY LINK" I'd like to know how to fix this.
This is the link that shows the problem 
http://wave.webaim.org/report?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.poirier-m.com%2FWCCPMobileTesting%2F6ideas.html&js=2

an example of code that doesn't get the Empty Link error would be nice.

Comment: I don't see where it says ERROR - EMPTY LINK.

Comment: If you already fixed the problem, please say so and explain how.